# spark streaming - use previous calculated dataframe in next iteration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a streaming app that take a dstream and run an sql manipulation over the Dstream and dump it to file

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd => 
{spark.read.json(rdd)
.select("col")
.filter("value = 1")
.write.csv("s3://..")
```

now I need to be able to take into account the previous calculation (from eaelier batch) in my calculation (something like the following):

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd => 
   {val df = spark.read.json(rdd)
val prev_df  = read_prev_calc()
 df.join(prev_df,"id")
 .select("col")
  .filter(prev_df("value)
  .equalTo(1)
  .write.csv("s3://..")
```

is there a way to write the calc result in memory somehow and use it as an input to to the calculation

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the persist() method on a DStream? It will automatically persist every RDD of that DStream in memory.
by default, all input data and persisted RDDs generated by DStream transformations are automatically cleared.
Also, DStreams generated by window-based operations are automatically persisted in memory.
For more details, you can check https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#caching--persistence
https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/api/streaming/spark/streaming/DStream.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking only for one or two previously calculated dataframes, you should look into Spark Streaming Window.

Below snippet is from spark documentation.

```
 val windowedStream1 = stream1.window(Seconds(20))
 val windowedStream2 = stream2.window(Minutes(1))
 val joinedStream = windowedStream1.join(windowedStream2)
```

or even simpler, if we want to do a word count over the last 20 seconds of data, every 10 seconds, we have to apply the reduceByKey operation on the pairs DStream of (word, 1) pairs over the last 30 seconds of data. This is done using the operation reduceByKeyAndWindow.

```
 // Reduce last 20 seconds of data, every 10 seconds
 val windowedWordCounts = pairs.reduceByKeyAndWindow((a:Int,b:Int) => (a + b), Seconds(20), Seconds(10))
```

more details and examples at-
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations